# Where are file associations stored?

Tags: files, mime-type, file-association

How does Ubuntu or any other Linux systems store file associations?

Is there some `/etc/asscociations` file or something?

I know that I can right click on file and change it via "open with", but I'm just curious to know how it's stored internally.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The file manager (Nautilus, by default) uses the [MIME type](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mime-type) of a file to determine which program to open it with.
When an application is installed, it can specify what MIME types it can open and the command to use to open the files in the .desktop file which is placed in `/usr/share/applications`. This is the file used for menus, desktop shortcuts, etc.

For example, GIMP has the following .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=GNU Image Manipulation Program
GenericName=Image Editor
Comment=Create images and edit photographs
Exec=gimp-2.7 %U
TryExec=gimp-2.7
Icon=gimp
Terminal=false
Categories=Graphics;2DGraphics;RasterGraphics;GTK;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=GIMP
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=General
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.7.2
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-OtherBinaries=gimp-2.7
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=application/postscript;application/pdf;image/bmp;image/g3fax;image/gif;image/x-fits;image/pcx;image/x-portable-anymap;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/x-portable-graymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/x-psd;image/x-sgi;image/x-tga;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-xwindowdump;image/x-xcf;image/x-compressed-xcf;image/tiff;image/jpeg;image/x-psp;image/png;image/x-icon;image/x-xpixmap;image/svg+xml;application/pdf;image/x-wmf;image/jp2;image/jpeg2000;image/jpx;image/x-xcursor;
```

See the `MimeType` field - this lists the supported MIME types.The `Exec` field tells the system to use the command `gimp-2.7 %U`, replacing '%U' with the files to open. (Note GIMP 2.7 is a version I have installed from a PPA, so is higher than the current version in the Ubuntu repositories).

When the application package is installed, the system extracts this MIME type data into a more easily accessible database because looking in each .desktop file would take too long if it was done every time a file was opened.

This tells the system what applications *can* be used for that MIME type and provides the applications in the 'Open With' list. The default is defined elsewhere. The file `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` provides the information for the system defaults. Unless you choose otherwise, these are the applications used when you 'Open' a file.

Comment: After changing MIME types in `/usr/share/applications` `.desktop` files, is there a command to re-create that MIME database to see new associations in action?

Comment: Yes. `sudo update-desktop-database` See http://jarrpa.net/2011/10/28/creating-custom-url-handlers-in-ubuntu-11-04-11-10-gnome-3-0/

Comment: A more appropriate place for local changes is `/usr/local/share/applications`.  I think gtk looks there, too, by default.  It does on my system, but it's been upgraded (not reinstalled) since Ubuntu 7.04 or so.

Comment: Ubuntu seems to follow freedesktop.org: http://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html , an **awesome** project.

Comment: FWIW, I had to use `sudo update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/` because the .desktop files were local.

Comment: Maybe add, that user specific information is stored in `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`

Comment: Every time I run `qtfm` it overwrites `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. I have no `defaults.list` files anywhere. I've removed any `mimeinfo.cache` files I could find and they haven't been re-created. I've confirmed the `/usr/share/applications/mupdf.desktop` entry has a `application/pdf` mime type. I've regenerated the database. I have no `/usr/local/share/applications` directory. I can't even see where `qtfm` is getting it's defaults from but when it's supposed to support `mimeapps.list` I don't see how "support" involves overwriting what should be the user preferences.

Answer (score 27):

To supplement dv3500ea's excellent answer, I would like to add some information about what happens when you change your associations.

While the defaults.list (which you can find by typing 'locate defaults.list') provides the list of applications that are associated with each MIME type, any customizations that you make are stored in your home directory, in ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list. So if you add or remove associations, or change the default association, this file is updated.

The GNOME Desktop System Administration Guide at http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/ does not appear to discuss mimeapps.list, but I found the following description on http://live.gnome.org/SysAdminGuideUpdate:

> mimeapps.list is located in
>   $XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications. Its
>   purpose is to add or remove mime
>   associations from applications.
>   nautilus writes
>   ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
>   when the user makes changes in the
>   "Open With" dialog.

Comment: But using Ubuntu 12.04, I realize that the `mimeapps.list` is overridden by entries in the `defaults.list`.

Comment: on 14.04, I was able to s/vlc/mplayer/ in my `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, and running processes like pcmanfm picked up the changes without restarting.  (mplayer.desktop is just runs mplayer.  I had one lying around from an old mplayer install in /usr/local, I guess.  IDK if having a `MimeType=list;` was needed or not.

Comment: More precisely, `mimeapps.list` can be anywhere in the following search path: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html

Comment: I find `qtfm` mercilessly overwrites `~/.local/sahre/applications/mimeapps.list` from some unknown set of defaults regardless of what I do :-(. The QtFM release notes call this "support".

Answer (score 26):

I found that on my system (Debian Jessie) there's also a `~/.config/mimeapps.list` that had an association I accidentally created to open a specific file type with gedit. None of the standard ways of correcting this (default application settings, Thunar's *open with* property) reflected this, but gedit was the default application.

I was able to remove the line from `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and now the correct application opens the file.

Comment: Thanks, you accidentally helped me to fix Firefox opening everything in Gedit. On openSUSE 13.2 I removed the line with "application/octet-stream=org.gnome.gedit.desktop;". :)

Comment: since ubuntu 15.04 the user-specific modifications are also stored in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Comment: More precisely, `mimeapps.list` can be anywhere in the following search path: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html

Answer (score 13):

I was able to set an association like this:

```
xdg-mime default xnview.desktop image/jpeg
```

You can also remove associations and do other things: `man xdg-mime`

I did not need to run `sudo update-desktop-database`.

Comment: Thanks for putting this answer in. I thought it might fix my problem with `qtfm` overwriting `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` but unfortunately `xdg-mime query default application/pdf` still shows `mupdf.desktop` whether there is an entry in `mimeapps.list` or not, and `qtfm` still overwrites my `mimeapps.list` and doesn't respect what `xdg-mime` says. I wonder where the other location is for the defaults that `qtfm` is reading?

Answer (score 10):

On Ubuntu 18.04, I've found the order of precedence to be as follows, from strongest to weakest:

1. `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`
2. `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`
3. `~/.config/mimeapps.list` ("Open With Other Application" will update this)

   - See [Alex Martian's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16580/where-are-file-associations-stored/1163724#comment2519246_1163724) below; #2 and #3 may be out of order.
4. `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
5. The first encountered match in the `mimeinfo.cache` registry of compatible applications, which are generated from the `.desktop` files present in `/usr/share/applications` and `/usr/local/share/applications`, and can be regenerated using [`update-desktop-database`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/update-desktop-database.1.html).
6. (Never used) `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`

Comment: I noted when in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` there are several entries on one line, only first apprears in applications to open file with (as default if not overwritten), I don't know why others are present.

Comment: It seams "strongest" means more upper level, `~/.config/mimeapps.list` AFAIK overwrites `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. My `~/.config/mimeapps.list` did have (better) information in it but `qtfm` wasn't respecting it and was still over-writing `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` from some other mysterious location.

Answer (score 9):

I found this link concerning default association, it might be helpful.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_Applications 
for global association:

```
/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

per user association:

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

syntax is as follow:

```
[Added Associations]
mimetype=desktopfile1;desktopfile2;...;desktopfileN
...
[Removed Associations]
mimetype=desktopfile1;desktopfile2;...;desktopfileN
```

**[Added Associations]** section is used to specify preferred (default) applications in decreasing preference. which means **desktopfile1** is the most preferred and **desktopfileN** is least preferred.
**[Removed Associations]** section is used to explicitly remove any previously inherited associations.

Comment: This comes from an **archlinux** site, doesn't necessarily apply on Ubuntu, `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, however the user said in Ubuntu or  other Linux systems, this mean this is an answer to his question too :P.

Comment: This answer is perfectly ok if you replace `mimeapps.desktop` with `defaults.desktop`

Answer (score 7):

Create a file `truecrypt.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` with the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Icon=
Exec=/usr/bin/truecrypt %U
Name=truecrypt
Comment=manage truecrypt volumes
```

then edit the file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and add the following line:

```
application/octet-stream=truecrypt.desktop
```

I found out the mime type of Truecrypt by following running this command:

```
file --mime-type -b <any truecrypt filename>
```

Comment: Nice answer, because it works for those of use who use kde, but have a couple of gtk-native programs, like firefox.

Answer (score 6):

**`mimeapps.list` search path**

Others have mentioned this file, but none have explained it's location precisely.

The freedesktop.org standard says at https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.html :

> The lookup order for this file is as follows:
>
> | Location | Usage |
> | --- | --- |
> | $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/$desktop-mimeapps.list | user overrides, desktop-specific (for advanced users) |
> | $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list | user overrides (recommended location for user configuration GUIs) |
> | $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/$desktop-mimeapps.list | sysadmin and ISV overrides, desktop-specific |
> | $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/mimeapps.list | sysadmin and ISV overrides |
> | $XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list | for completeness, deprecated, desktop-specific |
> | $XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/mimeapps.list | for compatibility, deprecated |
> | $XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list | distribution-provided defaults, desktop-specific |
> | $XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/mimeapps.list | distribution-provided defaults |

and then the default values for those environment variables is given at https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html :

- `$XDG_DATA_HOME`: `$HOME/.local/share`
- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`: `$HOME/.config`
- `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`: none, appended to `XDG_DATA_HOME`
- `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`: none, appended to `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`

Older versions of Ubuntu may not check `~/.config`, so make sure you try `~/.local/share` as well.

Commands like:

```
 xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium-browser.desktop
 xdg-settings get default-web-browser
```

will automatically edit those files.

Answer (score 3):

[Freedesktop.org](https://freedesktop.org/) (previously called the X Desktop Group, thus the "XDG" abbreviation) is the group currently driving X standards like this ([learn more at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org)).

[warvariuc's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/639099/260416) already mentions [xdg-mime](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-mime.html) usage like:

```
xdg-mime default xnview.desktop image/jpeg
```

After lots of playing with image editors and viewers, I ended up with different viewers for different image types with almost no consistency, especially among the rarer image types.

I took the above command and assigned it to each of the MIME types controlled by the image viewers and then created a new `image-viewer.desktop` by cloning one of them (this is optional, you can merely reuse your favorite).  Next, I manually verified that none of the MIME types would be incompatible with my new preferred application.  Finally, I set that application to be the default for all of the other applications' MIME types:

```bsh
sed '/^MimeType=/!d; s///; s/;/\n/g' \
  /usr/share/applications/{ristretto,geeqie,gthumb}.desktop |sort -u \
  |xargs xdg-mime default image-viewer.desktop
```

This examines the `.desktop` files for each of the viewers ([Ristretto](https://web.archive.org/http://docs.xfce.org/apps/ristretto/getting-started), [Geeqie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geeqie), and [GThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/gthumb) in my case), extracts the MIME definition (which is prefaced by `MimeType=` and then contains a semicolon-delimited list), removes the (previously matched) preface label, and splits the list into one entry per line.  `sort -u` then removes the redundant lines, then they're handed to `xdg-mime` to set the new defaults.

(If you want to test this before running it live, change `xargs` to `xargs echo` and it will print the resulting command instead of running it.)

This technique should work for anything you want to reclaim for a target app.  You don't even need to create a new `.desktop` file (you can use an existing one).  I did that extra step so that when I inevitably change my allegiance between image previewers, I merely need to change that one file.

Answer (score 3):

For all users:

> /usr/share/applications/defaults.list

Each user has a config file for overriding these defaults:

> ~/.config/mimeapps.list

see also https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html for places that might be used for overriding defauts.

You must know the mime-type of the file you want to change it's association.

Also all associations can be handled-changed in command line using:

> xdg-mime

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer rather than a comment as I've been on this all morning and others may find this a crucial aspect of the file associations on Linux.

#### Free Desktop Specification

As linked in the references, the Free Desktop specification describes how the `mimeapps.list` file(s) are used to determine which applications open which types of files.

ArchLinux wiki also has some great references, also linked below.

Other answers go into this in sufficient detail.

#### "Hidden" and "NoDisplay" Entries

To get to the point of this answer, you may not have noticed that your desktop entry file (`<application>.desktop` file usually found in `/usr/share/applications`) may have a line where it states that `Hidden=True` or `NoDisplay=True`.

###### "Hidden" Entries

"Hidden" does *not* mean just invisible. It means "deleted" or exactly the same as "just not there". If your desktop entry is "Hidden" not only is it as good as deleted, but aggressive file managers (such as QtFM) may strip it from your `mimeapps.list` file on start up.

If you're running into problems, just remove the "Hidden" line and your troubles may be over.

###### "NoDisplay" Entries

Well, the Free Desktop spec is very clear and explicit about "NoDisplay", but it turns out not all applications may be so clear.

"NoDisplay" means "don't list the application in menus", but do respect it and use the entry for launch, even as the default handler, even though it's not displayed in the menus. There are genuine use-cases for this, and that's why the "NoDisplay" feature is provided.

Not all applications apparently understand this. Some file managers treat "NoDisplay" as "Hidden", and will then even **strip out your application entry from `mimeapps.list`**, as if `mimeapps.list` belonged only to them, and without telling you, as if you're a Windows user or something, and only paid for the OS. But it's not even correct behaviour.

#### Workarounds and Solutions

1. Check your desktop entries for the applications of concern.
2. Definitely remove any "Hidden=True" entries if the application is in use
3. As a workaround, remove "NoDisplay=True" from your entry, applications may behave better
4. Read the other answers to this question; I have not duplicated their content
5. *In extremis* take a master copy of your preferred `mimeapps.list` or `defaults.list` file, and then delete all others, including `mimeapps.cache`

Clearly the Free Desktop specification might work a little better if applications actually used it, and also if they allowed users to use it for themselves, according to Linux principles, instead of overwriting `mimeapps.list`, either correctly or incorrectly, at a whim, without telling the user.

#### References

- https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_entries
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Default_applications
- https://github.com/rodlie/qtfm/issues/190
- https://github.com/rodlie/qtfm/issues/69