# How does Ubuntu create "user-defined" file associations?

Tags: 10.04, file-association

I'm afraid my question's gonna look like a rant, but I'm really curious how such terrible setting have got created.

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/23866/10802), *any customizations that you make are stored in your home directory, in ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list*. However I've found there the following (list shortened and sorted for clarity):

```
application/x-shellscript=userapp-emacsclient-ETH68V.desktop;emacs23.desktop;gedit.desktop;openoffice.org-writer.desktop;userapp-thunderbird-5IXU8V.desktop;...;userapp-emacsclient-4DBR8V.desktop;writer.desktop;userapp-thunderbird-5IXU8V.desktop;

text/x-sql=emacs23.desktop;userapp-emacsclient-ETH68V.desktop;gedit.desktop;openoffice.org-writer.desktop;userapp-thunderbird-    video/mp4=totem.desktop;vlc.desktop;

video/mpeg=vlc.desktop;
video/x-flv=vlc.desktop;
video/x-matroska=totem.desktop;vlc.desktop;
video/x-ms-wmv=totem.desktop;vlc.desktop;
video/x-msvideo=vlc.desktop;
```

- Why is `emacsclient` twice there? These entries are supposed to be user-defined, but I'm sure I didn't create them. Nor did I ever reinstalled emacs (which could possibly explain this duplicity).
- Does anybody think `openoffice.org-writer` should get used for editing shell scripts? Or even Thunderbird? Moreover, it's twice there. It wasn't me, I'm sure.
- Why does video get associations depending on it's format? Can't I specify something like `video/*=vlc.desktop` (possibly with exceptions for strange formats my favorite player is incapable to play)?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience using the default applications section in `System settings > Details > Default applications` isn't all that reliable for some reason that I can't figure out, but `Nautilus->RightClick->Open with->SetAsDefault` works every time

Answer (score 0):

First, if you did not make those connections than someone was in your account and made those connections. Please note however, that "make a connection" does not mean that you edited that file. It means e.g. that you chose to open something via `Nautilus->RightClick->Open with..`. Those are **not** provided by Ubuntu as you know, since you quoted the answer from the other askubuntu question. The Ubuntu defaults are here: `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`.

Second, there is a good reason to have different applications for different video types: some players can not play all types, but still be the preferred application **if** they are able to.

In general, I would not advice you to edit that file, but follow one of those steps:

1. `System settings > Details > Default applications` should open something like this:
   [image]
   Here you can change the preferred applications for important *summary* mime types.
2. Use the freedesktop.org utility `xdg-mime` to specify an application for a specific mime type: `xdg-mime default myapp.desktop mymimetype` (replace myapp.desktop and mymimetype with whatever you need)
3. Or of cause use the right click menu from Nautilus as you already know:`Nautilus->RightClick->Open with..`