# Opening text files with emacsclient by default

Tags: 16.04, 10.04, default, file-association

I want to open all text files with emacsclient. On 10.04 it used to [mostly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137542/how-does-ubuntu-create-user-defined-file-associations) work, but on 16.04 it's completely broken:

- emacsclient exists and works fine
- it's missing from the "open with" menu
- the "add" button does nothing at all
- there are duplicates

Then I added an `emacsclient.desktop` entry to `~/.local/share/applications` manually as found in my 10.04, but it does nothing at all.

[image: missing-emacsclient]

Comment: Still struggling with the same. Seems nobody has a workable solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the association with text files via `xdg-mime` as well:

```
xdg-mime default emacsclient.desktop text/plain
```

Also, make sure you've started the Emacs server via the command  `M-x server-start`.

Comment: you could use `--alternative-editor ''` option to use existing server or start a new one automatically: `Exec=/usr/bin/emacsclient -a '' -c %F` See [How to use one instance of emacs as the default text editor? [Linux\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4458800/4279)

Answer (score 0):

`mimeapps.list` file is present in  `.local/share/applications`
open it and add `text/plain=emacs.desktop` in it so that all text files will open in emacs