# How do I open weblinks with Firefox, not Gedit?

Tags: firefox, gedit, url, .desktop

I save links as files, rather the using bookmarks. I just drag the URL field from Firefox onto my desktop/folder.

Recently these stopped opening in Firefox, and started "opening" in Gedit. Even in Gedit, the file errors. The only way I can open these to even see the link is by using vim, having navigated to the file from the terminal.

There are a number of threads with similar problems, to solutions to which I have tried to no avail. <[THIS THREAD](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=916621)> describes exactly my problem, but no solution is posted.

Example URL File Contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to Google
Type=Link
URL=http://www.google.com
Icon=text-html
```

Contents of my ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list:

```
[Added Associations]
application/x-rpm=ubuntu-software-center.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird.desktop;
message/rfc822=thunderbird.desktop;
application/x-extension-eml=thunderbird.desktop;
inode/directory=vlc.desktop;
application/pdf=inkscape.desktop;kde4-okularApplication_pdf.desktop;
text/x-python=vim.desktop;gedit.desktop;
application/pgp-keys=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
image/x-hdr=gedit.desktop;
text/plain=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
audio/x-vorbis+ogg=totem.desktop;
application/octet-stream=gedit.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/ftp=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/chrome=firefox.desktop;
text/html=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-htm=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-html=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-shtml=firefox.desktop;
application/xhtml+xml=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-xhtml=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-xht=firefox.desktop;

[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird.desktop
message/rfc822=thunderbird.desktop
application/x-extension-eml=thunderbird.desktop
application/pdf=kde4-okularApplication_pdf.desktop
text/html=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/about=chromium-browser.desktop
x-scheme-handler/unknown=chromium-browser.desktop
audio/x-vorbis+ogg=totem.desktop
x-scheme-handler/ftp=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/chrome=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-htm=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-html=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-shtml=firefox.desktop
application/xhtml+xml=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-xhtml=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-xht=firefox.desktop
```

And here is a screen-shot of Gedit trying to open these:[image: Gedit trying to open these:]

Any help super appreciated, as this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Post the link into the question. Someone else can  add it as a picture ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears I borked things when following <[a tutorial](http://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/add-new-application-to-open-with-other-application/)> to set things up so I could just right-click files to open them in `vim`.

The two resources I found most helpful to figure this out were:

- <[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16580/where-are-file-associations-stored)>
- <[And This](http://www.libre-software.net/change-the-default-application-ubuntu-linux)>

There was clearly nothing wrong with the url files, as navigating to their parent directory and running the following opened them in [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) just fine:

```
# firefox url-name.desktop
```

This indicated that there was an issue with the `Exec` line for [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) getting run properly. I then discovered that I had a symbolic link to my `firefox.desktop` file by running the following in my user specific directory:

```
# ls -l ~/.local/share/applications/
```

As described in the second link, `mimeapps.list` is a user-specific list of default applications to be used to open various mime-types (i.e. file types).

I renamed this file to archive it, and then I created a sym-link to the `defaults.list`:

```
# ln -s /local/share/applications/defaults.list/ ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Restarting [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox), and everything worked! Phew. Hopefully, this helps somebody. Now to see what I did wrong with that vim tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's the problem, but it looks like a wrong URL in your example:

> `URL=http://www.google.html`

The top-level domain (`.com`, `.de`, …) is missing.

*Maybe* the gedit error could be a result of this, because of the `/`, *if* gedit might think that it's a local file path (instead of a Internet URL)? Doesn't seem plausible, though (why does gedit even bother? Shouldn't it simply show the text file content anyway?). Is gedit trying to *navigate* to the URL?

Comment: Thanks unor. I did a manual edit of a link to make it more generic, and missed this. I solved my question, but was required to wait to post the answer as a new member.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem in 16.04 where web links on my desktop was being opened on gedit instead of firefox with the error:

```
Could not open the file “https://...”. Unable to handle “http:” locations."'
```

[image: Error - Unable to handle “http:” locations.]

I was able to fix the problem by editing:

```
~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

Find the entry:

```
application/octet-stream=gedit.desktop;
```

This entry will mostly likely under the `[Added Associations]` heading. Move this entry to under the `[Removed Associations]` heading. Save the `mimeapps.list` file and the behaviour should be fixed immediately.