# How is it determined which application is to open a file of specific mime-type?

Tags: files, mime-type, file-association

I saw [the following question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16580/where-are-file-associations-stored), but I can't comment yet. So I decided to create a separate one.

I have both `transmission` and `deluge` installed. And I have no association for `application/x-bittorrent` mime type, based on contents of `/usr/share/gnome/applications/defaults.list` and `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. But it seems `.torrent` extension has association and it's `transmission`. That is when I double-click a `.torrent` file, `transmission` is opened. The same goes for when I open it in `chromium`.

The question is how come it is `transmission`? Why not `deluge`? Both have this mime type in their `.desktop` files. Are the associations stored somewhere else?

**UPD**

```
$ egrep bittorrent /usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
egrep: /usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list: No such file or directory
$ egrep bittorrent /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
application/x-bittorrent=transmission-gtk.desktop;deluge.desktop;
$ egrep bittorrent /usr/share/applications/defaults.list

$ egrep bittorrent /home/yuri/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
$ egrep bittorrent /home/yuri/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
egrep: /home/yuri/.local/share/applications/defaults.list: No such file or directory
```

The default is `transmission`. Changing order in `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` changes the default application. Probably one shouldn't rely on this behavior.

Comment: There are other places as well, such as `~/.gnome/share/apps`. Different distros and different desktops do this slightly differently. [freedesktop.org](http://freedesktop.org/) has a [spec-of-sorts](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mime-actions-spec/). You've found the two places typical for Ubuntu. If they're both empty, I would guess the system has to pick *one*, and has some deterministic way of doing that. `~/.local/.../mimeapps.list` is Ubuntu's standard user-level override, and that's where AliNa's dialog stores its settings.

Comment: @Salt please change your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways a MIME type and a `.desktop` file are associated.

**Method 1**

The first way is through `*.list` MIME config files (many exist on the system, see below). For example, a typical entry in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` might be:

```
[Default Applications]
application/x-bittorrent=transmission.desktop;deluge.desktop
```

This means that the preferred application is `transmission`, if it cannot be found, then the second choice is `deluge`.

**Method 2**

The second way is through the `.desktop` file itself. The application advertises which MIME types it can open. For example, in `transmission-gtk.desktop`, we have the following line

```
MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;
```

which indicates that this program can handle those two MIME types.

**Which Application To Use?**

The [association between MIME types and Applications](http://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.html) is defined by the `freedesktop.org` standards. Here are the steps taken when determining which application (i.e. which `.desktop` file) to launch for a given MIME type.

**Step 1:** Look for an association in the MIME config files. The lookup order is as follows:

```
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/$desktop-mimeapps.list    
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list    
$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/$desktop-mimeapps.list    
$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/mimeapps.list    
$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list    
$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/mimeapps.list    
$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list   
$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/mimeapps.list
```

**Step 2:** Once all levels have been checked, if no entry could be found, the implementations can pick any of the `.desktop` files associated with the MIME type, taking into account added and removed associations (which exist in the MIME config files).

Although you do not have any MIME config files, the reason that `transmission` is being used is because of **Step 2** as defined by the standard. Check your `transmission-gtk.desktop` file to see whether it advertises its ability to open torrents.

I suggest reading the linked document for a full understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the default one in a file **Properties** > **Open with** [tab]; for example for a video file:

[image: Open with]

You can simply select your preferred app and set it as default.

You can also see the **open with** list when right-clicking on the file. Double-clicking opens it with the default one.

Comment: It answers a different question: how to change file association? And I'm asking how to explain the behavior I'm experiencing?

Comment: Do you mean that when you right click on a .torrent file there’s no app suggestion to open with? And also you mean Transmission is not the default one? I got from your question that Transmission is your default app for torrent; because you mentioned _double-clicking_. Double click runs the default app. So I thought you could set Deluge as the default.

Comment: I know how to change file association. I don't know why it is as it is. Why `transmission` is the default application for `.torrent` files. Or more precisely, where this information is stored. Gotta check out other variants suggested by `Salt`.