# Modify the list of programs presented to open images in evolution?

Tags: configuration, evolution, attachment

In Evolution, I can open a pull down menu to select an application for opening attached image files.  Since I have Gimp installed, it occurs on this list.  How can I remove this option from the drop down menu (I never want to run Gimp in this way, but I sometimes accidentially hit it)?

I've looked through `Edit->Preferences` but didn't see anything that looks like I can configure what applications are presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's nothing you configure in *Evolution*. Applications are rather registered globally with your system. But be aware that making it "unavailable" will be a global thing: you can either "unregister" Gimp from a given mime type *generally* or *not at all* (sure, that wouldn't keep you from open it manually).

Not that's clear where the association lies, I don't want to re-invent the wheel. For how to deal with them, please take a look at

- [Where are file associations stored?](https://askubuntu.com/q/16580/68291)

You're lucky, it even uses Gimp as example :) For more details on those "associations", you might wish to follow up to our [mime-type](/questions/tagged/mime-type) tag and browse its questions.