# how to associate a filetype with a program?

Tags: files, file-type

trying to associate .bluej files with bluej.

so i rightclick a bluej file ->properties ->open with
and here is the problem. it says:

"Select an application to open "pacjage.bluej" and other files of type "plain text document""

this means that also .txt files are opened with bluej. Which of course dont work.

is there a way around this?

Comment: Does this point you in the right direction: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16580/where-are-file-associations-stored ? It looks like you want to associate the .bluej filetype with a specific application - those are mime types in Ubuntu and that's what I suspect you're looking for but I'm unfamiliar with the format and application.

Answer (score 1):

You need a new mimetype for bluej files. Start a simple test to see why:

```
$ mimetype pacjage.bluej
pacjage.bluej: text/plain
```

Therefore create a new mime type

1. Create a new configuration via

   nano ~/.local/share/mime/packages/bluej.xml
2. Add the configuration below

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
     <mime-type type="text/bluej">
       <comment>bluej file</comment>
       <glob pattern="*.bluej"/>
       <glob pattern="*.BLUEJ"/>
     </mime-type>
   </mime-info>
   ```
3. Update the mime database

   ```
   update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
   ```
4. Check the mimetype of your `bluej` file once again

   ```
   $ mimetype pacjage.bluej
   pacjage.bluej: text/bluej
   ```

---

For a system-wide configuration use the configuration file

```
/usr/share/mime/packages/bluej.xml
```

and update with

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```