# Image viewer WebM compatible

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a lot a [WebM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) files mixed with PNG and JPEG files in a folder.

I would like to find an image viewer (or a video player ?) that will allow  me to browse through those JPEG, PNG and WebM files. It would be perfect if I could display a diaporama of all those mixed files.

Does an WebM compatible image viewer currently exist ? Or maybe a WebM greffon for the default Ubuntu image viewer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since VLC can open both images and WebM videos you could use VLC.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Caveats:

- From Files, you'll have to select all the files in the current directory, right click on one and click on "Open with VLC";
- To be able to do the above you'l have to [setup VLC so that it can open images' MIME types](https://askubuntu.com/q/16580/380067), otherwise "Open with VLC" won't be shown in the context menu if the selection contains both images and WebM videos.

Opening a terminal in Files' current directory and running this:

```
vlc *
```

instead works out-of-the-box.

You'll probably want to tick Tools -> Preferences -> All -> Playlist -> Play and Pause so that the images won't be played as a slideshow (this changes the default behavior; playing a specific playlist will override this settings with the playlist's setting):

[image: s1]

Answer (score 3):

gThumb Image Viewer can be used to open webm without problems and you can install it from Ubuntu Software Centre.