# 17.10 seahorse-nautilus mime association for "decrypt file", getting really frustrated at the ubuntu way

Tags: nautilus, encryption, mime-type, seahorse

I'm a proficient linux user, just recently I've been learning how to deploy server with ansible+vagrant so I just spent an entire week on centOS and various other flavour of linux getting a complex network to work.

I require to encrypt decrypt from nautilus context menu, I installed seahorse-nautilus and everything went fine, I created a key and everything is working, then I accidentally opened a .pgp file with textedit selecting open with from nautilus and this changed the mime association.

I cant't figure where does ubuntu actually stores mime association and I can't even find anymore decent documentation and specs about everything that ubuntu does its own way.

can't find where it changed it now, looked at all the usual places for mime associations and couldn't find the added association between pgp and textedit. I uninstalled seahorse-nautilus and reinstalled it (including a nautilus -q) but no luck, the text edit mime association stays.

can somebody please explain to me where does ubuntu adds mime association made with nautilus when you click open with application and how to either prevent that from happening or change it afterwards?

I'm getting really frustrated at ubuntu in recent years, seems like it's not even linux anymore and this might really be the last drop, might go to real linux like arch in the next couple days and forget this bloatware that ubuntu has become.

I checked

/usr/share/applpications/ etc. etc.
$HOME/.local/share/ etc.
/usr/share/gdm/greeter etc.

found many different config file holding mime association but nothing regarding pgp.

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are file associations stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16580/where-are-file-associations-stored)

Answer (score 2):

Did you check `~/.config/mimeapps.lst` ?

Comment: You don't have sufficient rep to post a comment. With more details you can change this comment in the form of an answer, into a real answer though.