# Find all programs associated with a MIME type

Tags: mime-type

How to find all programs associated with a MIME type? One could look for the MIME type
in the [default, system-wide directory](https://askubuntu.com/q/16580). For example, for `application/pdf`,

```
grep -ls application/pdf /usr/share/applications/*
```

lists all the program files in `/usr/share/applications` that are associated
with `application/pdf`.

But that would overlook [other directories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications#mimeapps.list), specially user-level directories.

Isn't there a command similar to

```
xdg-mime query default application/pdf
```

to list all associated programs, not only the default one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a short Python program for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gio
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print('Error: Exactly one command line argument needed')
    sys.exit(1)

for app in Gio.app_info_get_all_for_type(sys.argv[1]):
    print(app.get_id())
```

Save that in a file, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/mimeapps`. Then you can use it like

```
$ mimeapps text/plain  
emacs.desktop
libreoffice-writer.desktop
pluma.desktop
vim.desktop
```

Comment: If you haven't installed PyGObject (which provides the gi module), you can do so with: 
`sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev; pip install PyGObject`