# Where can I find a docu about available mime file types

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, mime-type

In the file

```
/etc/mailcap
```

are stored different mime file types like

```
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template;
text/plain;
application/vnd.sun.xml.draw;
application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template;
application/vnd.sun.xml.impress;
application/vnd.sun.xml.impress.template;
audio/midi;
audio/x-midi;
audio/mod;
application/x-troff-man;
text/troff;
application/x-troff-man;
text/troff;
text/html;
application/x-troff-man;
text/troff;
application/x-info;
audio/mpeg;
application/pdf;
application/x-pdf;
text/pdf;
text/x-pdf;
image/pdf;
image/x-pdf;
audio/midi;
audio/x-midi;
audio/mod;
application/x-bittorrent;
text/plain;
image/avs;
image/bie;
image/x-ms-bmp;
image/cmyk;
image/dcx;
image/eps;
image/fax;
image/fits;
image/gif;
image/gray;
image/jpeg;
image/pjpeg;
image/miff;
image/mono;
image/mtv;
image/x-portable-bitmap;
image/pcd;
image/pcx;
image/pdf;
image/x-portable-graymap;
image/pict;
image/png;
image/x-portable-anymap;
image/x-portable-pixmap;
image/ps;
image/rad;
image/x-rgb;
image/rgba;
image/rla;
image/rle;
image/sgi;
image/sun-raster;
image/targa;
image/tiff;
image/uyvy;
image/vid;
image/viff;
image/x-xbitmap;
image/x-xpixmap;
image/x-xwindowdump;
image/x-icon;
image/yuv;
text/plain;
text/html;
text/xml;
application/xhtml+xml;
application/xml;
application/rss+xml;
application/rdf+xml;
image/gif;
image/jpeg;
image/png;
x-scheme-handler/http;
x-scheme-handler/https;
x-scheme-handler/ftp;
x-scheme-handler/chrome;
video/webm;
application/x-xpinstall;
application/pkcs12;
application/pkcs12+pem;
application/pkcs7-mime;
application/pkcs7-mime+pem;
application/pkcs8;
application/pkcs8+pem;
application/pkix-cert;
application/pkix-cert+pem;
application/pkix-crl;
application/pkix-crl+pem;
application/x-pem-file;
application/x-pem-key;
application/x-pkcs12;
application/x-pkcs7-certificates;
application/x-x509-ca-cert;
application/x-x509-user-cert;
application/pkcs10;
application/pkcs10+pem;
application/x-spkac;
application/x-spkac+base64;
x-scheme-handler/telnet;
x-scheme-handler/rlogin;
x-scheme-handler/ssh;
application/vnd.openofficeorg.extension;
x-scheme-handler/vnd.libreoffice.cmis;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-flat-xml;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-flat-xml;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-flat-xml;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-flat-xml;
image/bmp;
image/gif;
image/jpeg;
image/jpg;
image/png;
image/tiff;
image/x-bmp;
image/x-pcx;
image/x-tga;
image/x-portable-pixmap;
image/x-portable-bitmap;
image/x-targa;
image/x-portable-greymap;
application/pcx;
image/svg+xml;
image/svg-xml;
application/x-gameboy-rom;
application/x-gba-rom;
application/x-genesis-rom;
application/x-nes-rom;
application/x-sms-rom;
application/x-snes-rom;
application/ogg;
application/x-ogg;
application/mxf;
application/sdp;
application/smil;
application/x-smil;
application/streamingmedia;
application/x-streamingmedia;
application/vnd.rn-realmedia;
application/vnd.rn-realmedia-vbr;
audio/aac;
audio/x-aac;
audio/vnd.dolby.heaac.1;
audio/vnd.dolby.heaac.2;
audio/aiff;
audio/x-aiff;
audio/m4a;
audio/x-m4a;
application/x-extension-m4a;
audio/mp1;
audio/x-mp1;
audio/mp2;
audio/x-mp2;
audio/mp3;
audio/x-mp3;
audio/mpeg;
audio/mpeg2;
audio/mpeg3;
audio/mpegurl;
audio/x-mpegurl;
audio/mpg;
audio/x-mpg;
audio/rn-mpeg;
audio/musepack;
audio/x-musepack;
audio/ogg;
audio/scpls;
audio/x-scpls;
audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;
audio/wav;
audio/x-pn-wav;
audio/x-pn-windows-pcm;
audio/x-realaudio;
audio/x-pn-realaudio;
audio/x-ms-wma;
audio/x-pls;
audio/x-wav;
video/mpeg;
video/x-mpeg2;
video/x-mpeg3;
video/mp4v-es;
video/x-m4v;
video/mp4;
application/x-extension-mp4;
video/divx;
video/vnd.divx;
video/msvideo;
video/x-msvideo;
video/ogg;
video/quicktime;
video/vnd.rn-realvideo;
video/x-ms-afs;
video/x-ms-asf;
audio/x-ms-asf;
application/vnd.ms-asf;
video/x-ms-wmv;
video/x-ms-wmx;
video/x-ms-wvxvideo;
video/x-avi;
video/avi;
video/x-flic;
video/fli;
video/x-flc;
video/flv;
video/x-flv;
video/x-theora;
video/x-theora+ogg;
video/x-matroska;
video/mkv;
audio/x-matroska;
application/x-matroska;
video/webm;
audio/webm;
audio/vorbis;
audio/x-vorbis;
audio/x-vorbis+ogg;
video/x-ogm;
video/x-ogm+ogg;
application/x-ogm;
application/x-ogm-audio;
application/x-ogm-video;
application/x-shorten;
audio/x-shorten;
audio/x-ape;
audio/x-wavpack;
audio/x-tta;
audio/AMR;
audio/ac3;
audio/eac3;
audio/amr-wb;
video/mp2t;
audio/flac;
audio/mp4;
application/x-mpegurl;
video/vnd.mpegurl;
application/vnd.apple.mpegurl;
audio/x-pn-au;
video/3gp;
video/3gpp;
video/3gpp2;
audio/3gpp;
audio/3gpp2;
video/dv;
audio/dv;
audio/opus;
audio/vnd.dts;
audio/vnd.dts.hd;
audio/x-adpcm;
application/x-cue;
audio/m3u;
application/x-java-archive;
application/java-archive;
application/x-jar;
application/x-tar;
application/x-compressed-tar;
application/x-bzip-compressed-tar;
application/x-tarz;
application/x-xz-compressed-tar;
application/x-lzma-compressed-tar;
application/x-lzip-compressed-tar;
application/x-tzo;
application/x-lrzip-compressed-tar;
application/x-lz4-compressed-tar;
application/x-zstd-compressed-tar;
application/vnd.debian.binary-package;
application/x-deb;
application/x-cd-image;
application/x-bcpio;
application/x-cpio;
application/x-cpio-compplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template;
text/plain;
application/vnd.sun.xml.draw;
application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template;
application/vnd.sun.xml.impress;
application/vnd.sun.xml.impress.template;
audio/midi;
audio/x-midi;
audio/mod;
application/x-troff-man;
text/troff;
application/x-troff-man;
text/troff;
pressed;
application/x-sv4cpio;
application/x-sv4crc;
application/x-rpm;
application/x-source-rpm;
application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed;
application/x-xar;
application/x-iso9660-appimage;
application/x-archive;
application/vnd.rar;
application/x-rar;
application/x-7z-compressed;
application/zip;
application/x-java-archive;
application/x-compress;
application/gzip;
application/x-bzip;
application/x-lzma;
application/x-xz;
inode/directory;
application/x-deb;
application/x-debian-package;
text/x-apt-sources-list;
text/x-apt-sources-list;
x-scheme-handler/steam;
x-scheme-handler/mailto;
application/x-xpinstall;
text/english;
text/plain;
text/x-makefile;
text/x-c++hdr;
text/x-c++src;
text/x-chdr;
text/x-csrc;
text/x-java;
text/x-moc;
text/x-pascal;
text/x-tcl;
text/x-tex;
application/x-shellscript;
text/x-c;
text/x-c++;
application/x-virtualbox-vbox;
application/x-virtualbox-vbox-extpack;
application/x-virtualbox-ovf;
application/x-virtualbox-ova;
text/plain;
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12;
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12;
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template;
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint;
application/zip;
text/plain;
image/avs;
image/bie;
image/x-ms-bmp;
image/cmyk;
image/dcx;
image/eps;
image/fax;
image/fits;
image/gif;
image/gray;
image/jpeg;
image/pjpeg;
image/miff;
image/mono;
image/mtv;
image/x-portable-bitmap;
image/pcd;
image/pcx;
image/pdf;
image/x-portable-graymap;
image/pict;
image/png;
image/x-portable-anymap;
image/x-portable-pixmap;
image/ps;
image/rad;
image/x-rgb;
image/rgba;
image/rla;
image/rle;
image/sgi;
image/sun-raster;
image/targa;
image/tiff;
image/uyvy;
image/vid;
image/viff;
image/x-xbitmap;
image/x-xpixmap;
image/x-xwindowdump;
image/x-icon;
image/yuv;
application/x-troff-man;
text/troff;
text/*;
text/*;
application/x-info;
application/x-tar;
application/x-gtar;
application/x-ustar;
text/*;
text/*;
application/vnd.debian.binary-package;
```

Are this all? Or depends it What programs are on my System?

I'm asking because I miss

```
x-content/video-dvd
```

[Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMultimedia/PlayerSupport)

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/16580/where-are-file-associations-stored

Comment: see also https://specifications.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/latest/

Comment: thank you @HuHa there they are. I mark my question as a duplicate.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-default-settings  which contains `mimeapps.list` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/lubuntu-default-settings/filelist) ; not sure what you meant by `docu` though

Comment: some kind of a list. I found debian wiki but ubuntu!=debian. And the specs from freedesktop.org are to much english text for me.  but now I have what I need.